# ASP.Net error while migrating website to a new server

Tags: asp.net, .net, server-migration

I was migrating my site to a new server, it's in .NET and I don't have much experience with the language. However I tried searching for the fix but had no success. Can someone help?

The error:

> compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in
>   this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends
>   the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/EnjoyMaster2.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
```

Comment: You need to post the code-behind file as well...

Comment: Did you move the bin folder also ?

Comment: yes the bin folder on this server

Comment: From what server to what server?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Inherits property and the class defined in this code file uses the same name and try and add the namespace before the class name e.g. `Inherits="namespace._Default"`.

[Error 4 Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).](http://www.developerfusion.com/thread/53581/error-4-make-sure-that-the-class-defined-in-this-code-file-matches-the-inherits-attribute-and-that-it-extends-the-correct-base-class-eg-page-or-usercontrol/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already checked: inherits attribute, codefile attribut, namespaces, and you still have problem it might be web.config issue (pageBaseType).

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    ...
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings/>
<system.web>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.UI.Page" />
...
```